# MS Access: Update query has no errors but does nothing

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Using this code to update a record

```
var query = "UPDATE myTable SET name = @name where id = @id";
using (DbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
{
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", item.Id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@name", item.Name));            
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)   {   }
}
```

But the record does not get updated. I get no error. The record exists in the DB. What is going on?

Comment: An update statement will not return an error if no data is updated. To determine if records were updated, check the return value of DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery. The result will contain the number of records affected.A value of zero means no records were updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but you have to add the parameters of your query in the order they appear in your query string. So flip these two lines

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", item.Id));  
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@name", item.Name));
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@name", item.Name)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@id", item.Id));
```

Comment: wut? what? why? uhh? who?

Comment: Yes, that's because the OleDb provider for MS Access **doesn't support** actual *named* parameters - it only supports **positional** parameters.